# This spams message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on('messageDelete', (message) => {
    logchan = db.get(`log_${message.guild.id}`)
  if (logchan === null) return;
  deletemes = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Message Deleted in ${message.channel.name}`)
  .setColor('#ff0000')
  .setDescription(message)
  .setFooter(`Message by ${message.author.username}`);
 return client.channels.cache.get(logchan).send(deletemes)
})
```

This spams the message and I have no Idea why all the code can be found here https://pastebin.com/d911u5Eb I have tried with and without the return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed there was an outside loop the fetch got closed at the message close and it messed up the whole program